# Is there a public bus from Budapest to Debrecen?

Tags: europe, budget, buses, hungary, central-europe

No results are obtained when I search on goeuro.com or busbud.com, and [Wikitravel's Debrecen page](https://wikitravel.org/en/Debrecen) only suggests car, plane and train.

However, this is between the biggest and second biggest cities of a country, and if cars can travel between the two cities, I'm surprised there's no bus.

Does anyone know if there is one?

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Budapest/Debrecen) lists both bus and train services between the two cities.

Comment: @CannonFodder: I wonder why you didn't write that in an answer rather than comment.

Comment: At the time I didn't have time to write up a proper answer. Zach Lipton has done it now using the same source.

Comment: @CannonFodder: But shouldn't you get the points for it?

Comment: Not bothered. I can't use the points for anything.

Comment: http://www.livinginhungary.info/how-to-use-the-hungarian-menetrendek-hu-bus-website.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rome2Rio shows](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Budapest/Debrecen) a twice-daily bus route operated by [Volanbusz](http://www.volanbusz.hu/en): [line 1060](http://www.volanbusz.hu/en/timetable/lines/line?menetrend=1060).

However, there are also many rail connections that take less time and cost a similar amount, so that may be preferable.

Comment: Some extra info: the lack of buses is intentional: in the past years, efforts have been made to reduce duplication between train and bus services, because trains are supposed to be faster, more comfortable and more environmentally friendly. As a result, bus services were heavily reduced (and their prices raised) on lines where trains are also an option.

Comment: @MártonMolnár Thanks for coming to share that (and welcome to travel.stackexchange, since I haven't had a chance to say so). That certainly makes sense; it didn't seem like there's a good reason to go by bus here unless you really dislike trains.